# Can we have some JavaFX classes in Java 6

Tags: java, javafx, java-6

I want to use `WebView` and `WebEngine` classes of `JavaFX` on Java6, am I able to do this or I must use Java 7?
I add the `jfxrt.jar` to the project, but it doesn't work, it gives the error below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/mohammad/workspace/Search/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/amd64/libglass.so
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:281)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:124)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:163)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Can't load library: /home/mohammad/workspace/Search/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/amd64/libglass.so
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1649)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:787)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1022)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryFullPath(NativeLibLoader.java:200)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibraryInternal(NativeLibLoader.java:88)
at com.sun.glass.utils.NativeLibLoader.loadLibrary(NativeLibLoader.java:31)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:73)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.loadNativeLibrary(Application.java:80)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory$1.run(GtkPlatformFactory.java:28)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory$1.run(GtkPlatformFactory.java:25)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkPlatformFactory.<clinit>(GtkPlatformFactory.java:25)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:188)
at com.sun.glass.ui.PlatformFactory.getPlatformFactory(PlatformFactory.java:20)
at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.Run(Application.java:103)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.startup(QuantumToolkit.java:271)
... 5 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/overview/faq-1446554.html#3

> What platforms are supported by JavaFX?
>
> JavaFX is available on
> Windows, Mac OS X, and Linux; for more details, see the JavaFX
> Certified System Configurations.
>
> As of JavaFX 2.2 and Java SE 7
> update 6, the JavaFX libraries are installed as part of Java SE; a
> standalone version of JavaFX 2.2 will remain available for Java SE 6
> users (Windows only) until Java SE 6 reaches End-of-Life in February
> 2013.

Since Java 6 is EOL, you are out of luck.

Comment: +1 even early version of Java 7, you are out of luck.  Time to upgrade to Java 7 update 40. ;)

Comment: It means there is no way, such adding Javafx library or etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you are building for Windows, you can download JavaFX 2.2.21 for Java 6  from this link 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/javafxjdk6-1728173.html , and add the library to your project dependencies.

Comment: No, I wanna use in Linux :(
Thanks

Comment: In that case... maybe it's time to upgrade :)